# Unable to update array with $[] positional operator. getting errors

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to update an array as specified on this MongoDB official tutorial [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#up._S_[]). The Steps that I have followed is:

1. Create collection name test:
2. Insert document in collection:

   > db.getCollection('test').insert({"_id" : 2,"grades" : [{ "grade" : 90,
   >   "mean" : 75, "std" : 6 },{ "grade" : 87, "mean" : 90, "std" : 3 },{
   >   "grade" : 85, "mean" : 85, "std" : 4 }]});
   >
   > db.getCollection('test').insert({"_id" : 1,"grades" : [{ "grade" : 80,
   >   "mean" : 75, "std" : 6 },{ "grade" : 85, "mean" : 90, "std" : 4 },{
   >   "grade" : 85, "mean" : 85, "std" : 6 }]});
3. Trying to update an array as specified in a tutorial:

   > db.getCollection('test').update(
   >          { },
   >          { $inc: { "grades.$[].std" : -2 } },
   >          { multi: true }
   >       )

As per tutorial, it must update the document. But, instead I receives an error:

```
cannot use the part (grades of grades.$[].std) to traverse the element ({grades: [ { grade: 80.0, mean: 75.0, std: 6.0 }, { grade: 85.0, mean: 90.0, std: 4.0 }, { grade: 85.0, mean: 85.0, std: 6.0 } ]})
```

I am using MongoDB 3.4 Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: What Mongo version are you running? The `$[]` operator has been introduced in 3.6

Comment: It is version 3.4

Comment: Well, there you have it? :)

Comment: @Boaz Thank you. I will update mongoDB

Comment: As noted, this is not supported in anything below MongoDB 3.6. Even if you do upgrade, I'm guessing by your usage of `getCollection()` you're probably using Robo 3T. If so beware that the product is still based on the core build of the mongo shell from 3.4. This means that various options such as `arrayFilters` get removed from update statements before they are sent to the server. See the notes on the canonical question for more information

Comment: @NeilLunn You are absolutely right. After updating mongo to 3.6 I am not able to fire these queries in Robo 3T.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51777183/cannot-use-the-part-to-traverse-the-element/51807509#51807509

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [$[] positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) to update the nested array elements...
It will modify all elements in the specified array field.

```
db.collection.update({}, { "$inc": { "grades.$[].std": -2 } })
```

Comment: It is working. But what if I have to update all elements in an array? Is $[] is deprecated?  I haven't found any use of it till now.

Comment: see the updated answer... you will find $[] in latest version of mongodb i.e. 3.6... https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/

Comment: Thank you! I will update it.

Comment: @AshishChoudhary Please update your answer accordingly, as it is now the accepted solution. If you can suggest an equivalent alternative for older versions, it would make a great answer.

Comment: Okay. Will update it

Comment: @Vaidya does above answer work for you?