# cannot use the part (...) to traverse the element

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongo-shell

Running `mongod` 3.6 and attempting to use [this example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#update-all-documents-in-an-array).

Here is the sample data:

```
> db.students2.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "grades" : [
        {
            "grade" : 80,
            "mean" : 75,
            "std" : 8
        },
        {
            "grade" : 85,
            "mean" : 90,
            "std" : 6
        },
        {
            "grade" : 85,
            "mean" : 85,
            "std" : 8
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "grades" : [
        {
            "grade" : 90,
            "mean" : 75,
            "std" : 8
        },
        {
            "grade" : 87,
            "mean" : 90,
            "std" : 5
        },
        {
            "grade" : 85,
            "mean" : 85,
            "std" : 6
        }
    ]
}
```

I am attempting to use the all positional operator as specified in the example:

```
> db.students2.update({}, { $inc: { "grades.$[].std" : -2 } }, {multi: true})
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 16837,
        "errmsg" : "cannot use the part (grades of grades.$[].std) to traverse the element ({grades: [ { grade: 80.0, mean: 75.0, std: 8.0 }, { grade: 85.0, mean: 90.0, std: 6.0 }, { grade: 85.0, mean: 85.0, std: 8.0 } ]})"
    }
})
```

Why is this error message occurring? Am I not following the documentation properly?

Comment: Run this command in mongo shell `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } )`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Hey, this worked! Would love it if you could provide an answer to this question as well as elaborate a little bit on how to fix this issue if using a MongoDB driver (such as the official one or `mongoose`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When switching from lower version to higher version for mongodb you have to set [**`setFeatureCompatibilityVersion`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/) for your mongodb which

> Enables or disables the features that persist data incompatible with
>   earlier versions of MongoDB. You can only issue the
>   setFeatureCompatibilityVersion against the admin database.

You can simply set this by running this command in mongo shell

```
db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } )
```