# Mongoose how to update document array item for given document array property item

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Consider the following collection of documents with an array of documents inside:

```
PurchaseOrder {
   id: '5b675d8180db9c13ac5b5c16',
   productItems: [
      { 
          quantity: 10,
          discount_id: '5af6452dcab5ce0ee2d47e63'
      },
      { 
          quantity: 10,
          discount_id: '5af6452dcab5ce0ee2d47e66'
      },
      { 
          quantity: 12,
          discount_id: null
      },
      { 
          quantity: 9,
          discount_id: '5af6452dcab5ce0ee2d47e63'
      },
      { 
          quantity: 7,
          discount_id: '5af6452dcab5ce0ee2d47e66'
      },
      { 
          quantity: 3,
          discount_id: null
      },
      { 
          quantity: 5,
          discount_id: '5af6452dcab5ce0ee2d47e66'
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to update, programatically using mongoose, for all collection, all `discount_id's` where `discount_id` equals certain `id` (example: `5af6452dcab5ce0ee2d47e63`).

Here is my try:

```
let selectedDiscount = {
   _id: '5af6452dcab5ce0ee2d47e63'
}

PurchaseOrderModel.update(
        {},
        { $set: { "productItems.$[item].discount_id": null } },
        {
            multi: true,
            arrayFilters: [{ "item.discount_id": selectedDiscount._id }]
        }
    );
```

Unfortunatelly I'm getting an error `Can't use $set` with the above statement.

How can I achieve such an operation in a single mongoose call ?

Comment: What is your mongodb and mongoose version?

Comment: Mongo 3.6.4 and mongoose 5.2.7

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51777183/cannot-use-the-part-to-traverse-the-element?noredirect=1#comment90564708_51777183