# $[] (Positonal operator) not working in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

[`$[] (positional-all)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#up._S_[]) update operator has been added in mongodb version 3.6. but it is not working in mongoose.

I want to update all the elements of `allTasks` array of a particular user, whose `paid : 0`  to `paid :1`

The query which i am using is :

```
User.update({
        _id: userId,
        "allTasks.paid":0
    },{
        $set : {
            "allTasks.$[].paid":1
        }
    })
```

**UserSchema**

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    allTasks: [{
        paid: Number // 0: unpaid, 1: paid
        //other fields
    }],
    //other fields
});
```

The above given query is not working, can anyone tell me, if i am missing something, or doing something wrong?

Comment: what is your mongoose version?

Comment: Its `4.13.14`. I think this maybe the problem

Comment: update mongoose version  to 5.x and `setFeatureCompatibilityVersion` to 3.6....  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51777183/cannot-use-the-part-to-traverse-the-element/51807509#51807509

Comment: This is exactly what i am trying to do right now.

Comment: My mongodb version is already 3.6+. Do i still need to `setFeatureCompatibilityVersion` ?

Comment: yes... Kindly have a look at the answer

Comment: Thanks, updating it to version 5.x worked, but i didnt need to use `setFeatureCompatibilityVersion` for it to work.

Comment: Great !!! Glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who is facing the same issue:

The issue was `Mongodb` & `mongoose` version.

- MongoDB version should be 3.6+
- Mongoose version needs to be 5.x or more

Also you might need to use `setFeatureCompatibilityVersion : 3.6`.

**From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51777183/cannot-use-the-part-to-traverse-the-element/51807509#51807509) answer:**

When switching from lower version to higher version for mongodb you have to set [setFeatureCompatibilityVersion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/) for your mongodb which

> Enables or disables the features that persist data incompatible with
>   earlier versions of MongoDB. You can only issue the
>   setFeatureCompatibilityVersion against the admin database.

You can simply set this by running this command in mongo shell

```
db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } )
```