# MongoDB update all elements of nested array within all documents

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection (called Clients) which contains multiple documents, each one representing a client. Each client document contains an array of phoneNumber documents. I would like to update all phoneNumber documents in all the client documents my collection to add a readOnly attribute to each phoneNumber document.

The challenge is that some of the phoneNumber documents have a readOnly attribute which I think is throwing me off...

Example JSON document below;

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5baa8e5da61b7842284937b7"),
    "clientID" : "00001",
    "firstName" : "Jonathan",
    "middleName" : "Herbert",
    "lastName" : "Alexander",
    "dateOfBirth" : "1965-04-04",
    "email" : "jonalex@hcare.com",
    "phoneNumbers" : [ 
        {
            "phoneID" : "001",
            "number" : "(404) 242-5939",
            "phoneType" : "HOME"
        },
        {
            "phoneID" : "001",
            "number" : "(404) 242-5939",
            "phoneType" : "HOME"
            "readOnly" : true
        },
        {
            "phoneID" : "001",
            "number" : "(404) 242-5939",
            "phoneType" : "HOME"
        }
    ],
    "gender" : "M"
}
```

In this example, I would like all phoneNumber documents to have the readOnly:false attribute.

I have tried using the following...

```
db.Clients.update(
   {},
   { $set: { "phoneNumbers.$[].readOnly" : true } },
   { multi: true}
)
```

...but it is giving me an error about not being about to use the part to traverse the element, so I am stuck.

How can I update all the documents in this collection to add the readOnly field to all elements in each documents' nested phoneNumbers array?

Comment: Your `update` is fine (tested on MongoDB 4.0). I guess you need to update your mongodb to a higher version

Comment: Please post the error and version as well

Comment: You are missing a coma in second element, index 1 in phone numbers array, after the phoneType field, I tried and its working fine.

Comment: The error I receive is "annot use the part (phoneNumbers of phoneNumbers.$[].readOnly) to traverse the element ({phoneNumbers: [ { phoneID: "001", number: "(404) 242-5939", phoneType: "HOME" } ]})" and I'm running on MongoDB 3.4.

Comment: The JSON isn't the problem - the above is a cut down version on my actual document.

Comment: You need to update your mongodb version to 3.6 to use `$[]` the all positional operator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot use the part (...) to traverse the element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51777183/cannot-use-the-part-to-traverse-the-element)

Answer (score 0):

Here would be an example query.
This will push the desired element onto each phone numbers document. If you are not attempting to

```
var results = db.Clients.find({"phoneNumbers.readOnly" : {$exists : false } });
results.forEach(function (result){
    result.phoneNumbers.forEach(function (doc){
       doc.push({"phoneNumbers.$[].readOnly" : true })
    })
});
```

Comment: I think you're missing a closing bracket from line 4 - but even with that I get an error, doc.push is not a function.

Comment: Sorry about that, the problem was a ")"