# how update the values of array inside other array on mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need help, I am trying to update the data inside of the array `content` inside of the `stage` array:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a95b1581ddd0d2c60b90612"),
  "country": "Chile",
  "name": "Xiaomi",
  "start": new Date("2018-02-28T00:00:00-0300"),
  "end": new Date("2018-03-03T00:00:00-0300"),
  "budget": 5000000,
  "instructions": "efaw",
  "status": null,
  "createdAt": new Date(1519568976029),
  "budgetAccum": 2465914.3070999998599,
  "brief": {
    "stage": [
      {
        "cantPost": 1,
        "cantStories": 1,
        "desc": "Descripción",
        "title": "Title of etapa",
        "_id": ObjectId("5bad2e6814bc8ae0450d79a1"),
        "content": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "desc": "Descripción contenido",
            "hashtions": "#hashtag / @mentions",
            "media": "photo or video",
            "participants": [

            ],
            "type": "post or history",
            "title": "Title of contenido"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

my Query is this:

```
const updateContent = await this.update({
    "_id": ObjectId(campaignId),
    "brief.stage._id": ObjectId(data.id),
    "brief.stage.content.id": data.idContent
}, {
    "$set": {
        "brief.stage.content.$.desc": data.content.desc,
        "brief.stage.content.$.hashtions": data.content.hashtions,
        "brief.stage.content.$.media": data.content.media,
        "brief.stage.content.$.participants": data.content.participants,
        "brief.stage.content.$.type": data.content.type,
        "brief.stage.content.$.title": data.content.title,

    }
});
```

And the error is this:

> {
>       "data": {},
>       "message": "cannot use the part (stage of brief.stage.content.0.desc) to traverse the element ({stage: [ { cantPost: 1, cantStories: 1, desc: \"Descripción\", title: \"Title of etapa\", _id: ObjectId('5bad2e6814bc8ae0450d79a1'), content: [ { id: 1, desc: \"Descripción contenido\", hashtions: \"#hashtag / @mentions\", media: \"photo or video\", participants: [], type: \"post or history\", title: \"Title of contenido\" } ] }, { cantPost: 1, cantStories: 1, desc: \"Descripción\", title: \"Title of etapa\", _id: ObjectId('5bad3932206981e377a31971'), content: [ { hola: \"true\", adios: \"false\" } ] } ]})",
>       "name": "Campaign-engine",
>       "type": "BAD_REQUEST",
>       "statusCode": 400

Any explanation and how could I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: What is your mongodb version? you can use `arrayFilters` here

Comment: the versions is this ^4.1.2

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`arrayFilters`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) in mongodb 3.6 and above

```
db.getCollection('testcollections').update(
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5a95b1581ddd0d2c60b90612") },
  { "$set" : {
    "brief.stage.$[e1].content.$[e2].desc" : 1,
    "brief.stage.$[e1].content.$[e2].hashtions" : 2,
    "brief.stage.$[e1].content.$[e2].media" : 3,
    "brief.stage.$[e1].content.$[e2].participants" : 4,
    "brief.stage.$[e1].content.$[e2].type" : 5,
    "brief.stage.$[e1].content.$[e2].title" : 6
  }},
  { "arrayFilters": [
    { "e1._id": ObjectId("5bad2e6814bc8ae0450d79a1") },
    { "e2.id": 1 }
  ]}
)
```

Comment: In this query: e1 and e2 is the index? the response is  "data": {
        "ok": 0,
        "n": 0,
        "nModified": 0
    }

Comment: no they are not index. they are identifiers https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/

Comment: Test with mongo shell. My response `WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })`

Comment: the code return  "data": { "ok": 0, "n": 0, "nModified": 0 }

Comment: Have you converted your id to objectId ?

Comment: Ok final thing try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51777183/cannot-use-the-part-to-traverse-the-element/51807509#51807509