# mongo operator to update all matching items in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
messages: [
    {
        user: "5c57c85a9354fa24ad749137",
        text: "hello",
        unread: true
    },
    {
        user: "5c57c85a9354fa24ad749137",
        text: "world",
        unread: true
    }
]
```

I am trying to update all array elements where id does not match given id with the $[] but nothing happens

```
ChatSchema.update(
        {_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.conversationId), "messages": {$elemMatch: {"user": {$ne: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.userId)}}}},
        {$set: {"messages.$[].unread": false}},
        {multi: true}
        ).exec()
```

And when I use the single $ operator it only updates the first element found.

I am using mongo version 4.0.6 with mongoose version 6.7.0

Answer (score 1):

Matching criteria should be the [**`$[identifier]`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)

```
ChatSchema.update(
  { "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.conversationId) }},
  { "$set": { "messages.$[msg].unread": false }},
  { "arrayFilters":[{ "msg.user": { "$ne": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.userId) }}] }
)
```

Comment: I tryed it out and same result, nothing happens

Comment: Remove `$ne` operator and check whether it works or not and then add  `$ne`

Comment: No, it does not update with or without the $ne operator, but it does update when I use a single $ instead of $[msg], the problem is that it only updates the first match

Comment: @I'mnothuman Run this command `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4" })`

Comment: Pls have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51777183/cannot-use-the-part-to-traverse-the-element/51807509#51807509

Comment: Still you cannot able to explain what is not working

Comment: Ok got it. Run this `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "4.0.6" })`

Comment: I also ran that and got no results

Comment: It does not give any result it just sets the `setFeatureCompatibilityVersion` of your database. Have look at the answer mentioned in the above comments

Comment: No, I mean that I set it to that version and ran the query and nothing happened